# My entropy calculation method is returning values greater than 1 in strange cases. Any ideas?

Tags: java

My entropy calculation method returns the correct number almost every time. But in a few cases like if the list is `{.3333, .3333, .3333, 0, 0}` This returns `1.584962500621156` which is not right.

Here is the code for my entropy calculator:

```
private double calcEntropySimple(double[] list){
    // Calculate entropy
    double entropy = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if(Double.isNaN(list[i])){
            list[i] = 0;
        }
        if (list[i] > 0) {
            entropy -= list[i] * log2(list[i]);
        }
    }
    return entropy; 
}
```

and my `log2()` method:

```
private static double log2 (double x) {
   return (Math.log(x)/Math.log(2)+1e-10);
}
```

Comment: What is correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider

```
let a = log2(.3333) --> -1.5851
let b = a * .3333   --> -0.5823

0 - b - b - b - 0 - 0 = 1.584962500621156
```

So it looks like your code is doing exactly what you asked it to.

Comment: I suppose you're right. I must be calculating entropy incorrectly, although I pulled the formula from a textbook.